# How to use UIGraphicsRendererFormat for UIGraphicsImageRenderer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, cgcontext, uigraphicsrenderer

I need to use UIGraphicsRendererFormat for my UIGraphicsImageRenderer to change its scale but I can't find even one example online. This is my code, I appreciate any help:

```
//Based on documentation I know that I have to create an instance from
UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat and set its scale to my desired scale but how can I use it???

UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat * format = [UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat defaultFormat];
format.scale=1.0;
UIGraphicsImageRenderer*renderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc]initWithBounds:self.bgImageView.layer.bounds];

UIImage*image= [renderer imageWithActions:^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext*_Nonnull myContext){
        [self.bgImageView.layer renderInContext: myContext.CGContext];
}];
```

Documentation : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsrendererformat?language=objc

Comment: Do you want to create image with some resolution form existing image?

Comment: Not in this case, I put two imageviews on top of eachother and set their frame and want to do this using uigraohicsimagerenderer which works great but i want to do it without caring about device scale, I want it to render always at scale 1

Comment: _bgImageview.layer.mask = _fgimageview.layer; just a simple masking via uigraohicsimagerenderer because its faster this way and its just for preview and it works but I wsnt it to do it at scale one always. Documentation says its possible if i use uigraphicsimagerendererformat but i don't know how to!?!

Answer (score 1):

Using this API might fix your issue:

```
   UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat * format = [UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat defaultFormat];
   format.scale=1.0;
   UIGraphicsImageRenderer *renderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200) format: format];
```

[See this doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer?language=objc)